# Uniform norm and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

Consider a sequence $f_n:R\to R,$ $f_n(x)=e^{-nx^2}$.

This sequence converges pointwise to 
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}1 & \quad \mbox{if } x = 0 \\ 0 & \quad\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \end{array} \right. 
$$

Now $\|f_n-f\|_\infty=\sup|e^{-nx^2}-f(x)|=$ ?

**What I don't understand:** Apparently it equals $1$, but I don't see why this is the case.

So because $1$ doesn't converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly.

*I need help on why the equality above equals $1$*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $$f_n\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) - f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\,?$$ Now let $k\to \infty$.

Comment: $f_n(\frac{1}{k}) = e^{-n(\frac{1}{k})^2}$ which tends to $1$ as $k \to \infty$.

And $f(\frac{1}{k})$ tends to zero?

Comment: Not only "tends to", it _is_ $0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, but why does that imply the equality holds for all $x$? Why did you choose $x=\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: It doesn't hold for all $x$, in fact, for $n > 0$, you have $0 \leqslant f_n(x) - f(x) < 1$ for all $x$, but the _supremum_ of $f_n(x) - f(x)$ over all $x$ is $1$, for all $n > 0$.

Comment: Ah, I understand. But why did you choose $x=\frac{1}{k}$? Is it because we're trying to get close to $0$?

Comment: Anything converging to $0$ but not equal to $0$ would do. $\frac{1}{k}$ is a simple choice.

Comment: Why can't we put $x=0$?

Comment: Because $f(0) = 1 = f_n(0)$, so that would not help us.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now. Could you post an answer and I shall give you the green tick for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0 \leqslant e^{-nx^2} \leqslant 1$ for all $n \geqslant 0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, hence $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty \leqslant 1$. Since $f_n$ is continuous with $f_n(0) = 1$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f_n(x) = 1.$$

But $f$ is discontinuous in $0$, and we have

$$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\x\neq 0}} f(x) = 0,$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\x\neq 0}} \left[f_n(x) - f(x)\right] = 1,$$

which implies $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty \geqslant 1$. Together, it follows that $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty = 1$ for all $n \geqslant 0$.